# Does this series converge? Can I use a rearrangemt to prove it doesn't?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{6}-\frac{1}{6}+ \cdots$$

I was thinking to use a rearrangment to get the harmonic series, but I don't know if that's valid, because the series should converge absolutely in order to say that all rearrangments converge to the same limit.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}&=\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{4}-\frac{1}{4}&=\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{5}&=\frac{1}{5}\\

\end{align}$$

Comment: @yohBS: and $1-\frac12 = \frac12$

Comment: @yohBS: This proves that this series diverges to infinity, because 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5... diverges to infinity am I correct?

Comment: @EpicGuy Indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rearrange, just group appropriately.  Some of the partial sums of this series are ...

Answer (score 1):

In general, rearrangement of conditional convergent series is okay provided

1. as a sequence, it converges to $0$.
2. the number of rearranged terms is bounded.

More precisely, let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be any sequence such that 
$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$.
Let $\pi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be any permutation of $\mathbb{N}$. Foreach $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the
two sets:

$$A_n = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n \}\quad\text{ and }\quad B_n = \{ \pi(0), \pi(1), \ldots, \pi(n) \}.$$ If the size of the symmetric differences of $A_n$ and $B_n$ is bounded by a number $C$ independent of $n$, i.e.

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\;\; \left| ( A_n \setminus B_n ) \cup ( B_n \setminus A_n )\right| = 2 \left| A_n \setminus B_n \right| \le C$$

then the series $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and its rearrangement 
$(a_{\pi(k)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ 
converge and diverge at the same time. When they converge,
they converge to the same limit.

For the question at hand, grouping them every two terms is essentially a rearrangement with at most one term replaced in each partial sum. Since these grouping/rearrangement results in a harmonic series which is known to diverge, the original series also diverge.